# Plotting temperatures of cities in Virginia using maps in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I am looking to plot the temperatures of different cities of Virginia using maps in R
I have the following variables with me for all the cities in my dataset.

```
Name of city, Latitude, Longitude, Temperature
```

Do I need additional variables or packages to show the temperatures.

Do I need to create an adjacency matrix or what functions should I be searching for to do this?

My end goal is to show the temperatures on the map with the corresponding city names.

Comment: Do you want to color by temperature or print it?

Comment: I would prefer to colour the temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame called `tempdat`, you could use the following code to put the temperature as text at each point:

```
library(maps)
map("state", "Virginia")
text(tempdat$long, tempdat$lat, label=tempdat$temperature)
```

For example, you could create `tempdat` by filtering the list of US cities built into the maps package for those in Virginia, then adding random temperatures:

```
data(us.cities)
tempdat= us.cities[us.cities$country.etc == "VA", ]
tempdat$temperature = round(rnorm(nrow(tempdat), mean=75, sd=5))
```

At which point the plot would look something like this (it's far too crowded, so if your set of cities are this crowded you may want to plot the temperature using color rather than text. Anything you can do with the `points` function built into R, you can do here).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Comment: To plot coloured points, the following might help, building on this answer: `tempdat$tempcut <- cut(tempdat$temperature, breaks=20); map("state", "Virginia"); with(tempdat, points(long, lat, pch=21, bg=heat.colors(20)[tempcut]))`. See `?colorRampPalette` if you want a custom color palette.

Comment: Hi I was trying it out. It worked well for Virginia.

Comment: I was trying it out for North Carolina as well

Comment: Now I used your advice on heat colours and I was trying to create a legend for it.  Here is my code- map("state", "North Carolina",main="Temperatures");
with(tempdat, points(Longitude, Latitude, pch=21,
                    
bg=heat.colors(5)[tempcut]),main="Kriged_Temperatures");
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("(-6.05,-4.82]"  ,"(-4.82,-3.6]" ,  "(-3.6,-2.37]" ,  "(-2.37,-1.15]",
"(-1.15,0.0762]"),
title="Legend", bty="n", inset=0.05,
lty=c( 1,-1,-1), pch=21,
col=heat.colors(5)); title("Temperatures")

Comment: .But my legend appears too big and it appears on the map. I am trying different places for the legend but it falls on the map. I want it to come below the map. I will attach the image

Comment: I am not able to attach my image. Basically the legend looks hideous on the map. I am trying to get it outside the map. Also is the order of the colours in the legend corresponding to the levels I have mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Reducing the box length or width is also not working